# BigQuery get table schema via query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to get BigQuery table schema info via query? (Something like **TABLES** but for schema). Not interested in cli approach.

What I'm trying to achieve is to perform an "incremental" update between 2 BQ tables (let`s say staging and production) with the same structure based on 1 "key" column, but with an automatic way to create the key and the rest of the hash based on all other columns.

In MySQL/mariadb would be something like. Get the columns from information_schema.columns for the specific table and string agg all columns based with COLUMN_TYPE = "PRI" and keep is as key, and then get all the others with a string agg also. This would auto generate a SQL query in order to do the rest stuff.

So the starting question is if there is something relevant to MySQL's `information_schema.COLUMNS`

Comment: Short answer: it is not currently possible but you could submit a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) for information schema support.

Comment: Fortunately it`s one of the times where your wish becomes a self fulfilling prophecy. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro

Answer (score 15):

Check out the Google documentation on [Getting table metadata using INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables). INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides metadata on your BigQuery datasets.

I believe you want the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project-id.dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
```

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE 2021**

It is possible now:

```
SELECT 
 TO_JSON_STRING(
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT( 
      IF(is_nullable = 'YES', 'NULLABLE', 'REQUIRED') AS mode,
      column_name AS name,
      data_type AS type)
    ORDER BY ordinal_position), TRUE) AS schema
FROM
  <YOUR_DATASET>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  table_name = <YOUR_TABLE>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see a couple of approaches, though they differ from the MYSQL approach -

1. If you *have* to use a `query`, just create a decorator to wrap a query with a `limit 1` clause. While you will be charged the same amount as running a full table scan, it *will* give you the the schema in the response (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) of the query job). Not the best approach due the possibly charges it might incur.
2. If you aren't tied to the `query` job, why not use the [tables get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) method? It [returns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource) a table resource object which contains the schema

Comment: 2: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-get-table#bigquery_get_table-python if you use the SDK clients.