# How to generate CREATE TABLE script from an existing table

Tags: google-bigquery

I create a table with Big Query interface. A large table. And I would like to export the schema of this table in Standard SQL (or Legacy SQL) syntax.

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940271/bigquery-get-table-schema-via-query) it is not possible to do so and there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905307) to obtain the output schema of a standard SQL query but seems like it was not finally implemented. Depending on what your use case is, apart from using `bq`, another workaround is to do a query with `LIMIT 0`. Results are returned immediately (tested with a 100B row table) with the schema field names and types.

Knowing this you could also automate the procedure in your favorite scripting language. As an example I used Cloud Shell as the CLI and API calls. It makes three successive calls where the [first one](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) executes the query and a jobId is obtained (unnecessary fields are not included in request URL), [then](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) we obtain the dataset and table IDs correspondent to that particular job and, [finally](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get), the schema is retrieved.
I used the `jq` tool to parse the responses ([manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)), which comes preinstalled in the Shell, and wrapped everything in a [shell function](https://www.shellscript.sh/functions.html):

```
result_schema()
{
QUERY=$1
authToken="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
projectId=$(gcloud config get-value project 2>\dev\null)

# get the jobId
jobId=$(curl  -H"Authorization: Bearer $authToken" \
              -H"Content-Type: application/json" \
              https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$projectId/queries?fields=jobReference%2FjobId \
              -d"$( echo "{
                \"query\": "\""$QUERY" limit 0\"",
                \"useLegacySql\": false
              }")" 2>\dev\null|jq -j .jobReference.jobId)

# get destination table
read -r datasetId tableId <<< $(curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $authToken" \
              "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$projectId/jobs/$jobId?fields=configuration(query(destinationTable(datasetId%2CtableId)))" 2>\dev\null | jq -j '.configuration.query.destinationTable.datasetId, " " ,.configuration.query.destinationTable.tableId')

# get resulting schema
curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $authToken" https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$projectId/datasets/$datasetId/tables/$tableId?fields=schema 2>\dev\null | jq .schema.fields
}
```

then we can invoke the function by querying a 100B row public dataset (don't specify `LIMIT 0` as the function automatically adds it):

```
result_schema 'SELECT year, month, CAST(wikimedia_project as bytes) AS project_bytes, language AS lang FROM `bigquery-samples.wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki100B` GROUP BY year, month, wikimedia_project, language'
```

with the following output as the schema (mind the selected fields using casts and aliases to modify the returned schema):

```
[
  {
    "name": "year",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "month",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "project_bytes",
    "type": "BYTES",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "lang",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
```

This field array can then be copy/pasted (or further automated) in the fields editor when creating a new table using the UI.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the DDL for a table with this query:

```
SELECT t.ddl
FROM `your_project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` t
WHERE t.table_name = 'your_table_name'
;
```

Comment: This is a good alternative to doing this within BigQuery.

Comment: This is a very easy and quick way to get ddl. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how it is possible using StandardSQL or Legacy SQL syntax. But you can get the schema in json format using command line.

From this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specify-schema-manual-cli) the command to do it would be:

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] > [PATH_TO_FILE]
```

Comment: Yes i Know that. :)