# BigQuery - Possible to query for column datatype

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a function that would allow us query the datatype of the column in BigQuery?

I'd like to find something like this:

```sql
WITH basket AS
    (SELECT "apple" AS fruit, 10 AS qty
    UNION ALL SELECT "pear" AS fruit, 7 AS qty
    UNION ALL SELECT "banana" AS fruit, 9 AS qty)

-- !!this doesn't work!!:
SELECT
    fruit,
    qty,
    DATA_TYPE(fruit) AS type1, 
    DATA_TYPE(qty) AS type2 
FROM basket
```

in order to return something like this:

```
+--------+-----+--------+-------+
| fruit  | qty | type1  | type2 |
+--------+-----+--------+-------+
| apple  |  10 | STRING | INT64 |
| pear   |   7 | STRING | INT64 |
| banana |   9 | STRING | INT64 |
+--------+-----+--------+-------+
```

Of course, my `DATA_TYPE()` function doesn't exist and I couldn't find anything comparable in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators)

Does this functionality exist somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: I don't think this is possible yet in SQL. You need to use the API to get the schema. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940271/bigquery-get-table-schema-via-query

Comment: @stewart-r - I can be wrong  - but somehow I feel that data type is not your final target but rather intermediate info that you need for some reason to use. Can you please share your use-case so we can help with possible workaround.

Comment: The use case is tricky to explain succinctly. We have a system where power-users can define their own calculation methods (which get represented as parts of BQ queries) and then get 'concatenated' (actually a little more involved than this but explanation is oos) together using meta-data. If we try to have the wrong data-type 'flowing' into the next calculation it unsurprisingly falls over. `CAST` can often help but occasionally we'd like to use conditional logic based on datatype. Workaround is simply another intermediate step so no biggie but thought the question was worth an ask

Comment: @Graham Polley Can you please post this as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Comment: @PhilippSh IMHO, Graham's comment is correct as a comment rather than an answer. My question was whether there was an existing (SQL) function. Graham (helpfully) linked to another question with an ALTERNATIVE approach but recognised and acknowledged that this isn't a direct answer (which probably doesn't exist). It's probably correct to leave as a comment then, no? The community can still benefit from comments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define `basket` as BQ view, then use SQL query

```
select column_name, data_type
from `your_project.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
where table_name = 'basket'
order by ordinal_position
```

You obtain requested type in `data_type` column.

I didn't find any way how to get SQL metadata directly from BQ query (analogy to Java `ResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName()`) and AFAIK it is not possible.

Theoretically it is possible that BQ client who calls BQ query will be changed to create view through API call, fetch metadata, fetch data and drop view but it is error-prone in many aspects (need for stronger rights, race conditions, billing issues). I didn't try this way. However, if you manage to gather all columns whose types you need to obtain to permanent view, it could be solution for your case.

Comment: GBQ reference on schemas is here FYI with other similar methods like COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

Comment: @wordsforthewise thanks, I understood OP is looking for runtime data type of column of query, not table.

Answer (score 2):

You can find 'JOB INFORMATION' tab within the query results,
and one of job info is 'Destination table'.

(Or you can see every recent(one week?) query result you executed in the 'PERSONAL HISTORY' tab below the query results and clicking 'Job ID' in the history list will lead you to some details page in which you can find a 'Destination table'.)

The temporary destination table (click the link) will show detailed information of the result table which includes data type of each column.