# Bigquery struct introspection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a way to get the element types of a struct? For example something along the lines of:

```
SELECT #TYPE(structField.y)
SELECT #TYPE(structField)
...etc
```

Is that possible to do? The closest I can find is via the query editor and the web call it makes to validate a query:

[image]

Comment: why not to make exact same call (dry run) and parse out needed info? should be easy! btw. what is really your use case for this? or this is just out of curiosity question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned already in comments - one of the option is to mimic same very Dry Run call with query built in such a way that it will fail with exact error message that will give you the info you are looking for. Obviously this assumes your use case can be implemented in whatever scripting language you prefer. Should be relatively easy to do.

Meantime, I was looking for making this within the SQL Query.
Below is the example of another option.
It is limited to below types, `which might fit or not into your particular` use case

```
object, array, string, number, boolean, null
```

So example is

```
select
  s.birthdate, json_type(to_json(s.birthdate)), 
  s.country, json_type(to_json(s.country)),
  s.age, json_type(to_json(s.age)),
  s.weight, json_type(to_json(s.weight)),
  s.is_this, json_type(to_json(s.is_this)),
from (
  select struct(date '2022-01-01' as birthdate, 'UA' as country, 1 as age, 2.5 as weight, true as is_this) s
)
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below approach.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM `your-project.your-dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your-table-name'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'your-struct-column-name'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) for more details using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for BigQuery.

Below is the screenshot of my testing.

**DATA:**
[image]

**RESULT USING THE ABOVE SYNTAX:**
[image]

Comment: got it, thanks. What if it's a literal struct (or from a CTE or composed)? In other words, not an unmodified column STRUCT ? For example, the one that I gave in the screenshot from the question?

Comment: Per my checking, you have to store your schema into a table or a view (as also suggested in this similar SO post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262224/bigquery-possible-to-query-for-column-datatype) to get the metadata of the columns (including struct columns).